# Proof of each of these identities

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In reading math history, I often encounter a picture like that here, which was apparently used by medieval mathematicians. Can someone point me to a reference - or show here - how each of these identities is derived? I get sine and cosine, which are obvious in fact. And I gather tangent is the length of the line tangent to the unit circle measured from the point of tangency to the x axis (though I never learned that in trig or later).

But how about secant, cosecant, cotangent? I'm sure these use geometric rules of corresponding triangles. But I'd like to see a complete explanation.

[image]

Comment: Name the angles and think in terms of similar triangles rather than thinking like "tangent is the length of the line tangent to the unit circle measured from the point of tangency to the x axis." Also see, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxNb1WG_Ido&ab_channel=3Blue1Brown

Comment: See my note ["(Almost) Everything You Need to Remember about Trigonometry, in One Simple Diagram" (PDF link via tricochet.com)](http://tricochet.com/math/pdfs/AlmostEverythingAboutTrig.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for those quick answers. The 3B1B video is right on point. I'm now reading the article Blue posted, which seems a more thorough treatment. Thanks to you both. Much obliged.

Comment: @Blue - great article. Really enjoyed that.